# Function pointing to a struct in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm analyzing a bit of code and can't quite seem to grasp some of the workings behind it.

```
struct dplist {
  dplist_node_t * head;
};

struct dplist_node {
  dplist_node_t * prev, * next;
  element_t element;
};

dplist_t * dpl_create ()
{
  dplist_t * list;
  list = malloc(sizeof(struct dplist));
  DPLIST_ERR_HANDLER(list==NULL,DPLIST_MEMORY_ERROR);
  list->head = NULL;   
  return list;  
}
```

From the header file:

```
typedef int element_t;
typedef struct dplist dplist_t;
typedef struct dplist_node dplist_node_t;
```

In the main function:

```
dplist_t * list = NULL;

int main(void)
{
     list = dpl_create();
     return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to view the dpl_create() function which is declared as a pointer a dplist struct (i think?). Why does the function need to be declared as a pointer to a struct in order to correctly execute what is written inside the function?

Comment: The function is declared as a function. The `dplist_t *` part before the function name is the return type.

Comment: Because it's returning a pointer to an instance of the struct (which has been dynamically allocated via `malloc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element in the declaration of a function in C, before the function's name, is always the type of the variable it will return.
In your case, the function is not declared as "a pointer to a struct", it just declares that it will return a pointer to a struct ("return list").
You can see another example in your code with the main function, which will return an INT ("return 0").

Answer (score 0):

dpl_create() allocates a new dplist_t and returns it.
In C you can't return objects that are dynamically allocated, you must return a reference(pointer) to them, hence

```
dplist_t *
```

Comment: Ah of course thank you! I have another question on the side if you don't mind. In the struct dplist_node which is typedeffed as dplist_node_t, there is both a 'next' and a 'prev' pointer to another dplist_node_t declared. Do I have to view these as pointers to one and the same struct or are these all separate instances of the initial struct?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 this is an implementation of a double-linked list. Such list consists of nodes where each node holds a pointer both to the previous node and to the next node. 'next' and 'prev' don't point to a struct, they point to a memory, each might point to a different memory that was allocated from the same struct.

Comment: Thanks @Arik, I understand this but what value does the pointer definition of next & prev to the type dplist_node_t hold then?

Comment: It doesn't hold a value, you could view it as NULL (although technically it isn't). To make it point to something, you'll have to explicitly assign it to something. https://pastebin.com/c41yrb9E This is an example of a function that creates a new node after a given node in the list. The given node has to point to the new node and the new node has to point to the given node.

Comment: *In C you can't return objects that are dynamically allocated'* what? Why? You can very well do `return *list` if the return type is `dplist_t` (and provided that list is copied somewhere, else it would leak)

Comment: @Arik I apologise, my previous answer wasn't formulated clearly. I didn't mean it literally holding a value but I think that your pastebin example makes it clear. Thanks.